# regex pattern to match this - start with and end with

Tags: regex

```
McDonalds 
MC Donald's 
mCDDONALDS 
m c donaldS
MC-DOnald'S
```

Pretty much want to search for an 'M' or 'm' and end with an 's' or 'S' and include everything in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[mM].*?[sS]$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^     # match line start
[mM]  # match m or M
.*?   # non-greedy pattern to match 0 or more of any character
[sS]  # match s or S
$     # match line end
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vE8qR3/1)

Comment: You regex parse only new line. In original question all word was in 1 line.

Comment: No they are on different lines but OP didn't do code formatting.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. 1 question since i am fairly new to regex - is there a reason the regex you provided doesn't work on http://www.regexr.com/ ??

Comment: Same regex will work on regexr.com as well, but check my demo link in answer as well. regex101.com is better site to built your regex

Comment: works great, thank you anubhava for the fast response

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  ([mM].*?[sS])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fyiqsxOk-drciX5i)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. 1 question since i am fairly new to regex - is there a reason the regex you provided doesn't work on http://www.regexr.com/ ??